# Cannot create an blank project with c++. But can create blank project with blueprint and other projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022, game-development, unreal-engine5

```
Running E:/Unreal/UE_5.3/Engine/Build/BatchFiles/Build.bat  -projectfiles -project="E:/program/week1/MyProject3/MyProject3.uproject" -game -rocket -progress
Using bundled DotNet SDK version: 6.0.302
Running UnrealBuildTool: dotnet "..\..\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.dll" -projectfiles -project="E:/program/week1/MyProject3/MyProject3.uproject" -game -rocket -progress
Log file: C:\Users\SREE\AppData\Local\UnrealBuildTool\Log_GPF.txt

Some Platforms were skipped due to invalid SDK setup: IOS, Android, Linux, LinuxArm64.
See the log file for detailed information


Generating VisualStudio project files:
Discovering modules, targets and source code for project...
Visual Studio 2019 does not support .NET 6.0 C# projects, these projects will not be added to the generated solution.
Please generate the Visual Studio 2022 solution if .NET 6.0 C# project support is required.
Microsoft platform targets must be compiled with Visual Studio 2022 17.4 (MSVC 14.34.x) or later for the installed engine. Please update Visual Studio 2022 and ensure no configuration is forcing WindowsTargetRules.Compiler to VisualStudio2019. The current compiler version was detected as: 14.29.30153
```

I have redownloaded unreal engine countless time still cannot create an blank project with c++

Comment: And did you try updating your visual studio installation, as the message tells you?

Comment: yes,when i update the visual studio it say install visual studio 2019 to create the project

Comment: What is "it"? Which program tells you to install Visual Studio 2019? And which version of Visual Studio 2022 do you have installed?

Comment: I mean an error message pops up and says to install visual studio 2019. I have visual studio 2022 17.8.3